# VBA - Setting value of a public variable in private submodule

Tags: excel, private, public, vba

Good afternoon.
Is it possible to set value of a public variable (for example: `var`) through a private submodule (for instance: `Worksheet_Change`) and then, after the end of the `Worksheet_Change` submodule's activity, refer to the `var` in a public submodule (`Sub`) existing in the same module (`Module1`) as the public variable `var`? I tried to do this but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try declaring it as `Public Name As Type`? It should be declared outside of any procedure or function.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: It's kinda short to be an answer but you can also store it somewhere in a cell, for example in named range like `Range("MyVar").Value = var`

Comment: It works. Since you didn't denied that there is a possibility to do the activity described inside the question, I'm almost sure that I have an internal problem in my macro. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers, no problem!

Comment: If you posted your code, someone could probably tell you why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I had an internal problem in my macro. It zeroed my variables. But I fixed that problem and now it works properly. I didn't post my code because of having more than one thousand lines. This thread is to me closed.